# Resultados de búsqueda en mi sitio aparezca en google search

Tags: seo

Lo que intento hacer es que, el resultado de la búsqueda dentro de mi sitio, también aparezca en google.

Es decir. En mi sitio se busca "electricista mar del plata" y da unos cuantos resultados de los electricistas en mar del plata. Lo que me gustaría, es que en el buscador de google, al poner "electricista mar del plata" salga la Url con los resultados de mi web. (No importa el orden en el que aparezca) simplemente quiero que aparezca en el buscador, la url de mi web que llevaría a los resultados.

¿Hay alguna URL en especial para que google te tome tu sitio web como un buscador?

¿Hay que poner algún title o keywords?

Comment: Gracias, ya lo corregí.

Comment: Si te ha funcionado puedes marcar la respuesta como valida para ayudar a la comunidad y a mi, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 4):

si todavía te sigue interesado lo que tienes que hacer es:

1. Poner título y descripción a tu pagina web
2. Entrar en [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about?hl=es) para poder añadir tu página y verificar que es tuya.
3. Por ultimo lo que tienes que hacer es buscar en la barra de búsqueda de google search console tu pagina con tu dirección y darle al botón de solicitar indexacion, dentro de unos días tendría que aparecer en google.
   Espero que esto te funcione.

Si ya tienes esto hecho y lo que quieres es un panel de información sobre tu empresa que aparezca tienes que hacer lo siguiente según [esta página](https://robertoardanaz.es/todos-los-tipos-resultados-google-aparecer/)

1. Haz una campaña de citación. Asegúrate de que tu negocio aparece en directorios de búsqueda local relevantes, tales como Yelp, tripadvisor, páginas amarillas, Booking para hoteles, etc. Proporcionar la mayor cantidad de datos posible, tanto de contacto como descripciones e imágenes te ayudarán a aumentar tu autoridad y relevancia.
2. Date de alta en Google My Business. Tal y como te he explicado en el punto anterior, incluye una foto   great preferred photo. Ésta foto no debe ser un logo, y debe representar bien tu negocio. Lo más recomendable es una imagen de   250×250 pixels o más grande.
3. Reseñas, reseñas, reseñas. A Google le encanta el contenido, otra cosa es qué haga con él y cómo lo muestre. Intenta obtener al menos 5 reseñas en Google, para que aparezan las 5 estrellitas en tu snippet. Asegúrate de pedir a tus clientes que escriban una reseña, e incentivales de alguna manera para terminar de convencerles.
   Lo más importante sería darte en alta en [Google Buisness](https://www.google.com/intl/es_es/business/).Espero que esto te ayude.

Comment: Hola brother como estas? muchas gracias por responder. Hice eso que me dijiste anteriomente hace unos 6 meses aproximadamente y efectivamente aparezco en google. Pero mi duda es como hacer que las búsquedas dentro de mi sitio también aparezcan. Gracias

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres hacer, lo podría explicar mejor?

Comment: Mi sitio web es un buscador de personas. Entonces al buscar por ejemplo "electricista" larga un par de resultados de las personas que son electricistas. Mi pregunta es como hacer para que google busque tambien a partir de mi sitio. Es decir, que yo pondría "electricista mar del plata" en google y aparezca en google mi sitio con la url de la busqueda es decir: www.misitio.com/search?search=electricista

Comment: Así como hacen los sitios como mercadolibre o olx. Al poner electricista o algo así, largan los resultados de sus busquedas en google.

Comment: Ahora actualizo mi respuesta para ayudarte.

Comment: Si no me equivoco lo que buscas es esto:
`<meta name="keywords" content="palabra clave 1, palabra clave 2, palabra clave 3"/>`